# PHP Do function after certain period

Tags: php

I'm working on an auction website. The auction time is set to 14 days. After 14 days I need to make some changes at database. What is the best solution ? Make function and call it at the beggining of script or make CRON?

Comment: If you want to call periodic cron job is good.

Comment: I agree with @web2students.com , it should be periodic cron job you run every day (for example) to check the auctions lthat created before 14 days ! :)

Comment: so cron every day to check whether the auction is over or not and then if it is over make changes at databse, right ?

Comment: i am confused, it's 14 days or 1 day?

Comment: The period of auction is 14 days. After 14 days I will change the type of auction to another and the peruiod wil change to 7 days

Comment: I don't know requirements, but you can create more than 1 cron jobs if it requires. also you can do with only 1 cron job, like 14 is divided by 7, so every 7 days cron can work for both,( if it's small job. if server takes too much time then 2 cron jobs is better.)

Answer (score 1):

Definitely most stable way is to use a CRON Job on a Unix Server for sure.

By the sounds of it though, you are going to want to schedule these jobs per auction created (14 days after each one). In this case you should look at managing the cron jobs via something like cron tabs. Here is a link to an amazing tutorial on how to set up a php / cron scheduling system:

[Managing Cron jobs with php](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/managing-cron-jobs-with-php-2/)

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the answer is *not* to change data at a certain time at all. The answer is to calculate the data as needed when needed. Just as an example, guessing that you want to change the auction status from "running" to "completed" or some such similar thing, instead of doing that:

1. when creating the auction, save an end time in the database in the form of a `DATETIME` field
2. whenever you query for "running" auctions, query `WHERE enddate > NOW()`

This way you can have the same effect with static data. Especially if you have many auctions running in parallel, changing the status of each one at a very specific time can be quite a problem; especially with an on-demand language like PHP.

Comment: I will have only 1 auction running at one time. After the 14 day I will need to set new period for after-auction sell. Which means I will be selling items which werent bidded for start price for next 7 days